# How can I highlight misuse of tabs and spaces according to current configuration?

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

I'm looking for a way that will highlight lines (or part of lines) that don't adhere to current tabs settings.

Say for instance, I have the following configuration in my `.vimrc`

```
tabstop=8 
softtabstop=8 
shiftwidth=8 
noexpandtab
```

Is it possible to highlight lines that don't adhere to the above settings ?

Answer (score 2):

My [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) checks the consistency of the used indent, and compares this with the buffer's indent settings. With a companion plugin, it can be triggered automatically for configured filetypes. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

Comment: Just tested you plugin. it failed with errors:

Error detected while processing function IndentConsistencyCop#IndentConsistencyCop..<SNR>139_IndentBufferInconsistencyCop:
line   19:
E117: Unknown function: ingo#query#ConfirmAsText
E15: Invalid expression: ingo#query#ConfirmAsText(a:inconsistentIndentationMessage, ['&Ignore', '&Highlight wrong indents...'], 1, 'Question')
...

Comment: You also need to install ingo-library (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433); it contains general-purpose functions used by all of my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

With those settings, a "line that doesn't adhere to current tabs settings" is basically "a line with spaces as indentation".

You can highlight such lines by searching:

```
/\v^\t* +\t*[^\s]
```

Broken down:

- `\v` − "very magic" mode so we don't have to use too many `\` later (see [`:help /\v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5cv))
- `^` − anchor to the start of the line.
- `\t*` − match zero or more tab characters.
- `+` − match one or more space characters.
- `\t*` − match zero or more tab characters again.
- `[^\s]` − match anything *except* a space character.

Or if you want to highlight the entire line, add `.*` to the end to also match the rest of the line:

```
/\v^\t* +\t*[^\s].*
```

If you don't want to clobber your search history with this, you can use `:match`:

```
:match Error /\v^\t* +\t*[^\s].*/
```

See [`:help :match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%3amatch).